# Fail when pushing an array of js objects to localStorage and then retrieving it and parsing

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I have an array of JS objects. For example: `var objectList = [{phone: true},{name: 'room'}]`.

I need to push it to localStorage, and then retrieve this array of object and continue to work with it.

I tried:

```
 localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(objectList));
 objectsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'));
```

And after this I got error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()

Also, when I try `console.log(localStorage.getItem('myObject'))` I obtained output:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

And when I try `console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('myObject'))` I got `string`.

How can I properly retrieve and parse array of objects so that I can then work with objects, which are stored in that array?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

```
var roomsList = [{
category: "ЛЮКС",
cond: true,
wifi: true,
smoke: true,
restrAbility: true,
veranda: true,
kingSizeBed: true,
numFree: 5,
numBusy: 2,
price: 1000,
image: "img/rooms/room0.jpg",
description: "Просторные двухкомнатные люксы с гостиными и уютными спальнями. В оформлении интерьеров использованы предметы антиквариата музейной ценности: мебель, музыкальные инструменты, торшеры и лампы из Богемского стекла - все это рождает уникальный, неповторимый стиль каждого номера. Мраморные ванные комнаты оборудованы гидромассажными ваннами. Все номера данной категории обращены окнами на живописный ансамбль.",
},
{
category: "СТАНДАРТ",
cond: false,
wifi: true,
smoke: false,
restrAbility: false,
veranda: false,
kingSizeBed: false,
numFree: 10,
numBusy: 8,
price: 120,
image: "img/rooms/room0.jpg",
description: "Просторные двухкомнатные люксы с гостиными и уютными спальнями. В оформлении интерьеров использованы предметы антиквариата музейной ценности: мебель, музыкальные инструменты, торшеры и лампы из Богемского стекла - все это рождает уникальный, неповторимый стиль каждого номера. Мраморные ванные комнаты оборудованы гидромассажными ваннами. Все номера данной категории обращены окнами на живописный ансамбль.",
 }]
```

and so on.. (14 objects in the array) All other logic and outputs are the same as I described earlier:

```
var roomsObject = localStorage.getItem('roomsObject');
if (!roomsObject) {
    localStorage.setItem('roomsObject', JSON.stringify(roomsList));
}
roomsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('roomsObject'));
```

Comment: I suspect the problem happens before you get to the point of saving the object. What happens when you `console.log(objectList)` **before** you save it?

Comment: When I `console.log(objectList)` before I save it I get `[Object, Object]`, so everything looks fine, there is an array of objects.

Comment: That doesn't look so fine to me. How about `console.dir(objectList)`?

Comment: In this case I get `Array[2]`

Comment: [Here is a fiddle with the code you posted.](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lvjsue5/) It works. There's got to be something you *haven't* posted that's causing your problem.

Comment: Also before saving array in localStorage I checked if it is already there. I call getItem and if it returns null I  save array in localStorage. Can this cause the error?

Comment: No, you save a **string** in local storage according to the code you posted.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is..

Comment: Me neither because you have not posted enough code. **The code you did post works just fine.**

Comment: Actually I have the same logic in my code, but different objects. I have an array of 14 objects like this: (see udpated question).

Comment: Can you post a fiddler with your actual code and _actual_ data?

Comment: Here is a fiddler with my actual code and data.
https://jsfiddle.net/8rbaLpt6/

Comment: Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong with my code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're storing the actual string `[object Object],[object Object]`, thats why the parse fails. Convert the object to JSON (string) before storing it.

Comment: There's a `JSON.stringify()` call in the OP's code.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Was a possibility before I saw that.