# LocalStorage save and load JS Object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to save an array consisting of multiple JS objects via localStorage.

I guess I'm having the same trouble as [Fail when pushing an array of js objects to localStorage and then retrieving it and parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863576/fail-when-pushing-an-array-of-js-objects-to-localstorage-and-then-retrieving-it), but there's no solution to it.

```
var featureArray=[];
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  if (feature) {
    featureArray.push(feature.values_);
  }
});

function saveFeatures() {
  localStorage.setItem('features', featureArray);
}
saveFeatures();
```

when I try to load them via `localStorage.getItem('features')` the output is something like:

> [object Object],[object Object]

But I actually want the values behind this structure to be saved.

I tried `localStorage.setItem('features', JSON.stringify(featureArray))` , but that throws the error

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

What am I doing wrong?

console.log(featureArray)'s output:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
    geometry:ol.geom.MultiPolygon {pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, revision_: 2, ol_uid: 39, …}
    krs:"Niedersachsen"
    sumarea_1_2014:20298
    sumarea_1_2015:16045
    sumarea_1_2016:19008
    sumarea_3_2014:3888
    sumarea_3_2015:27971
    sumarea_3_2016:15520
    sumarea_5_2014:11888
    sumarea_5_2015:14671
    sumarea_5_2016:31307
    __proto__:Object
1:
    geometry:ol.geom.MultiPolygon {pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, revision_: 2, ol_uid: 41, …}
    krs:"Nordrhein-Westfalen"
    sumarea_1_2014:23100
    sumarea_1_2015:2399
    sumarea_1_2016:21916
    sumarea_3_2014:11375
    sumarea_3_2015:31563
    sumarea_3_2016:20300
    sumarea_5_2014:859
    sumarea_5_2015:20633
    sumarea_5_2016:31101
    __proto__:Object
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

**UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/ytc26fju/3/** . hover over the dot to update the array. then click save and then the load button.

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('features')) ?

Also have a look at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: JSON parse/stringify ... localStorage can only store strings

Comment: What is the typeof featureArrays?

Comment: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('features')) throws unexpeted Token at position 0: [ (because [object Object],[object Object] is saved)

Comment: As well as JSON.stringify, the geometry property looks like an object.  So you will want so see if it has any options to serialize / deserialise it's data, and store / load this.

Comment: typeof(features) = object (before saving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` accepts an [*replacer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) parameter which will help you get rid of cyclic object while stringifying your object.

Here is a really simple implementation which will convert the second occurrence of a cyclic object to `null`:

```js
function cyclicsCleaner() {
  var seenObjects = [];
  return function cleanCyclics(key, obj) {
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
      if (seenObjects.indexOf(obj) !== -1) {
        return null;
      }
      seenObjects.push(obj);
    }
    return obj;
  }
}
// generate a cyclic object
var a = {};
var b = {
  cyclic: a
};
a.b = b;

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, cyclicsCleaner()));
```

Comment: @Revo can you share a link to this jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ytc26fju/3/ But I could fix it, my feature had a circular structure I had to get rid of first.

Comment: @Revo it's `JSON.stringify( obj, cyclicsCleaner() )` https://jsfiddle.net/ytc26fju/4/ `cyclicsCleaner` returns a function, so you need to call with `()`

Answer (score 3):

You do need to convert it to JSON to store it (with JSON.stringify) and parse it on the way out as localStorage stores strings and not objects.

The error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` means your data structure has an inherent loop where there's an object `a` that has object `b` as a property, which then has object `a` as a property...ad infinitum. Clearly you can't "write this out" as it's an infinite loop. Go through the object you are trying to save and you will probably see where it's going wrong - you seem to be pretty triggerhappy of pushing stuff to your `featureArray`.

Comment: found it. It was somewhere hidden in feature.geometry

Answer (score 3):

Set the item in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('features', JSON.stringify(featureArray));
```

Get the item from local storage.

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('features'));
```

Comment: As I wrote, that returns the error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Don't fully understand why, but a feature Object hat a circular structure. I had to do:

```
for (i=0;i<featureArray.length;i++) {
  delete featureArray[i].geometry;
}
```